# Azure AD B2C Forgot Password with Text instead of Email?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We currently have a user flow that when someone resets their password an email is sent and they copy the validation code and they can move on.

I would like to add the option that it can be from an email OR from a text message.

However I cannot seem to find any documentation on this.

Is it possible to do with User Flow in Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 1):

There are some samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#password-management) that show you how to do this.

e.g. "Demonstrate how to use a displayControl to conditionally process on the user's decision to verify their account via Email OTP or SMS".

I don't believe you can do it in user flow.